# redux causing component re-rendering

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a component which is connected to global store and getting some data from the global store. from some portion of this data is sent to another component via props and inside that component i have generated required jsx based on data. Also inside the child component mapdispatchtoprops is also used and it is also connected to global store as well.
The problem case scenario is child component re-renders depends upon the global store data.
The key for global store is like -

```
foods : {
  'list' : '',
  's'  : '',
  fetching : 0,
  slist : '',
  category : '',
  cproducts : ''
}
```

I guess what happening is the child component is re-rendered 7 times because the number of keys inside global store for foods is 7. if anyone is interested he/she can share his/her views

Answer (score 0):

Components have a render method which returns the JSX markup that it renders to the DOM. For change detection, React use a local state, which is only local to a component, when the state changes the component and its children are re-rendered to update the UI of the changed state.

A quote from the React documentation:

These components must not retain internal state, do not have backing instances, and do not have the component lifecycle methods. They are pure functional transforms of their input, with zero boilerplate. However, you may still specify .propTypes and .defaultProps by setting them as properties on the function, just as you would set them on an ES6 class.
PURE COMPONENT is one of the most significant ways to optimize React applications. The usage of Pure Component gives a considerable increase in performance because it reduces the number of render operation in the application.

So change your app to be like this

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
class Sample extends PureComponent {
  render() { 

        return (
<div>your structure here</div>
)
}
}

export default Sample;
```

Please read more on react PureComponent. [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/improve-performance-in-react-class-components-using-react-purecomponent-2438f432ddc4)